# Delete Proxy Environment Variable

Tags: macos, bash, proxy

I've been having proxy issues with npm and git.

Looks like the proxy is set as an environment variable in Bash

If I check with

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

I can see the proxy settings.

I can unset the proxy with

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
```

This only appears to last as long as the terminal window is open.

If I close and reopen the terminal the proxy is back again.

Is is it possible to delete the proxies when I'm out of office and then recreate them when I need them?

Comment: Where are they being set in the first place? If they are being set in your shell startup scripts you can only set them when you detect that you are at work. If they are set somewhere else then you can conditionally unset them in the shell startup scripts when you detect you are not at work. But that all depends on your ability to "detect" where you are at shell startup time.

Comment: How would I find out where they are being set? How would I detect where I am at shell startup time?

Comment: You can look in the shell startup files (`.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.) and see if they are set there. There's no simple answer to that second question though. You'd have to see what you can detect about the two environments. IP address, network neighbors, mapped drives, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find out where these environment variables are defined in your case.

Typically they are set in the `~/.bash_profile` file (Mac OS X) or `~/.bashrc` file (Linux). Since you tagged the question with `osx`, I assume that in your case they are set in `~/.bash_profile`.

Please check whether this file defines these variables. You can either do that using Finder (you need to show hidden files), or from a terminal by running `cat ~/.bash_profile`. Feel free to post the output in your question.

There's a small chance that they are defined in a system-wide file like `/etc/bashrc`. Feel free to check that file as well.

If you need to define/undefine the variables on a regular basis, I recommend that you create a script for each defining/undefining and place it in a location like `~/bin`. Then you can simply call the respective script when you open a new shell.

I handle this through the *Bash-it* framework. In my fork, I have added a proxy plugin that provides functions for this. Feel free to give this a try: https://github.com/nwinkler/bash-it/blob/master/plugins/available/proxy.plugin.bash

To answer your other question: There's no easy way to automatically detect and change the presence of a proxy from a shell window.